# How to prove this question using induction?

Tags: graph-theory, induction

The question is:
Prove that if graph $G$ is a **Connected Planar Graph** where each region is made up of at least $k\,(k\ge3)$ edges, then it must satisfy:

$e\ge\frac{k(v-2)}{k-2}$

$e$ means $G$'s number of edges, $v$ means $G$'s number of vertices

Then I am prepare using induction to prove this.But I don't know which variable should I use. The number of edges or the number of vertices? And I even don't know what $k$ means here. Is $k$ a number no less than $3$ or it equals to the minimum number of edges of $G$'s regions? Due to these doubts,I am confused how to start my induction correctly.

Comment: "Is $k$ a number no less than $3$ or it equals to the minimum number of edges of $G$'s regions?" Yes, it's both.

Comment: Is $k$ a unchangeble value or it will change as the graph changes?Like it will sometimes $k+1$,$k+2$ or others?

Comment: Different values of $k$ changes what graphs are allowed. $k=3$ is basically no restrictions. $k=4$ says "no triangles". If $k=5$, then we're saying "no triangles or squares". And so on. So among other things, you're asked to show that a connected planar graph with $v$ vertices and no triangles or squares has at least $\frac 53(v-2)$ edges.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you're using induction to prove a fact about relationship between a dependent variable and an independent variable, the induction is on the independent variable. Another generalization is that if you're proving an inequality, the induction is likely on the "less than" side. The expression $\frac {k(v-2)}{k-2}$ is written as if it's a function of $v$, making $v$ the indepedent variable. Furthermore, it it more common for the number of edges to be considered a dependent variable with respect to the number of vertices, than the reverse. None of this is iron clad rules, and having not worked out the proof myself, I can't say for certain, but I would strongly expect the induction to not be on $e$; I would expect it be on either $v$ or on the number of regions.

As for $k$, it is an integer that is greater than $2$, and it is a lower bound for the number of edges for each region. It is not necessarily the minimum; there is a difference between "minimum" and "lower bound". Lower bound for a set of values means that the values are never lower, while minimum means they are never lower, and at least one value is equal. So, for instance, I'm confident that 10 is a lower bound for the age of Fortune 500 CEOs, but it's not the minimum age, because no such CEO is actually 10.

Comment: It emphasizes that " each region is made up of at least $k(k≥3)$ edges" just because if  there exists some regions which break this lower bound,the graph may have some circles and it will not be a simple graph,right?So for every graph in this question,we can use $k$ as a lower bounce，and it is unchangable .

Answer (score 0):

It is no necessary to use induction.To resolve it,we need to use Euler's Formula:

> For a simple **Connected Planar Graph** G in which $e$,$v$,$f$ means its number of edges, verticesit,and regions,G must satisfy $v-e+f=2$.

And we also need:

> For a simple **Connected Planar Graph** G,its sum of the number of edges of all regions  is equal to twice the number of its edges.

We can supposed that the graph has $f$ regions.Since each region's edges is not less than $k$,the sum of the number of edges of all regions is not less than $kf$.In other words,

$2e\ge kf$

Then using Euler's Formula,we have:

$2e \ge k(2+e-v)\implies (2-k)e \ge k(2-v) \implies e \ge \frac{k(v-2)}{k-2}$

Then question resolved.

Comment: I am pretty certain that using Euler's formula means you're using induction. It's hidden, but I don't think you can avoid it.

Comment: But Euler's formula is a formula,We can directly use it,can't we?

Comment: Yeah, but hidden behind it (in its proof) is an induction argument that I don't think you can avoid.

Comment: That means I should also prove it?

Comment: No, but it means that claiming that a proof is "without induction" is usually just because you've hidden away where the induction happens, not because you have actually avoided induction. At least in places where induction is a very natural approach.

Comment: Oh,yes.$v-e+f=2$ is also actually proved by induction.